# When two client context scripts collide

Tags: 2013, javascript, publishing-page

Got a publishing page with two custom sections using javascript.

- the first is defined on the master page and filling some dropdowns in the left navigation bar
- the 2nd is defined on the page layout and creates a submenu in the main ContentPlaceHolder

Sometimes the first script is not executed and the dropdowns are not filled. Updating the page by Ctrl-F5 changes this behaviour sometimes. But reentering the page with a new browser instance shows the misbehaviour again.

Maybe the client context of the two scripts are influencing each other?
Any advice how to resolve this?

Setting a jquery timeout is a workaround but is it a good one?

Comment: A jquery timeout is a sign that your asynchronous code is poorly implemented. Without seeing the code that's about all anyone can say.

Comment: If possible, post some codes too..

Comment: If you are using global variables in your script, then avoid using them. Instead wrap your code within functions and try to call those function on page load.